# React Native Enforce English Keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible in a multilingual React Native app to enforce an english keyboard (for example, Email) for a specific TextInput?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean `<TextInput keyboardType="email-address" textContentType="emailAddress" />`?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, which is nice, but actually no I need an English keyboard for other TextInputs as well (name is always in English for example). Thanks though!

Comment: @DrorBar Do we have any solutions for this if the user changes the system language

Comment: @ManojPerumarath I didn't find a solution. The user can choose English or another system language,